# how can i split a string into tokens and store the tokens in a differents variables, C language

Tags: c

hi i have this code in C language : that split a string into tokens but what i want is that the tokens get store in different variables for example: 
a[]=+5000 b[]=-9000 c[]=7HH4 d[]= 0 because after the last comma i want that space for a variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[] = "+5000,-9000,7jj4,";

// Returns first token 
char *token = strtok(str, ",");

// Keep printing tokens while one of the
// delimiters present in str[].
while (token != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "-");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can `strcpy()` a token into whatever sufficiently-large array you want, or you can duplicate it (`strdup()` if you have it; `malloc()` + `strcpy()` if you don't) if you need to allocate space for it dynamically.  You can also save the pointer to the token if you intend to keep the original string around, unaltered.  If that doesn't answer the question then you'll need to clarify just what the question is.

Comment: About the changes in question ： `strtok` does not create `""` as token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what's the fun in using rolling wheels, C is all about creating something new. Here is the code -

```
int main (void ){

char str[] = "+5000, -9000, 7jj4";
char *p_str = str;
char a[10], b[10], c[10];
size_t a_count = 0,b_count = 0,c_count = 0;     // Need new index ever time for new token strings
size_t index = 0;

     while( *p_str ){
       if(*p_str == ',' ) { 
         p_str++; index++; p_str++;     // you can ignore p_str++ here.
      }    
        if(index == 0 && *p_str != ',' ){
          a[a_count++] = *p_str;        
       } else if( index == 1 && *p_str != ',' ){ 
           b[b_count++] = *p_str; 
        } else if ( index == 2 && *p_str != '\0' ){
            c[c_count++] = *p_str; 
         }      
       p_str++;
    }
   a[a_count] = b[b_count] = c[c_count] = '\0';
   printf("A : " ); puts(a); 
   printf("B : " ); puts(b);
   printf("C : " ); puts(c);
 return 0;
}
```

Note : You can do dynamic allocation also.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of how many times you called `strtok`, and copy the string to the appropriate place each time.

```
char a[50], b[50], c[50];
int count = 0;

char *token = strtok(str, ",");

// Keep printing tokens while one of the
// delimiters present in str[].
while (token != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", token);
    count++;
    switch (count) {
    case 1:
        strcpy(a, token);
        break;
    case 2:
        strcpy(b, token);
        break;
    case 3:
        strcpy(c, token);
        break;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign each variable from `strtok`.

```
char *a, *b, *c;

a = strtok(str, ",");
b = strtok(NULL, ",");
c = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to allocate a buffer for each token that is returned and store it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[] = "+5000,-9000,7jj4";

// We'll use this to allocate pointers.
//
char **tokens = NULL;
int totalTokens = 0;

// Returns first token 
char *token = strtok(str, ",");

// Keep printing tokens while one of the
// delimiters present in str[].
while (token != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "-");

    // Allocate first/next pointer
    //
    if (! tokens) {
        tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        if (! tokens) {
           // Handle malloc() error...
           //
        }
    } else {
        // Allocate next pointer
        //
        tokens = realloc(tokens, (sizeof(char *) * totalTokens);
        if (! tokens) {
            // Handle realloc() error.
            //
        }
    }

    // Use the newly allocates pointer to malloc() a buffer
    //
    tokens[totalTokens] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1));

    if (! tokens[totalTokens]) {
       // Handle malloc() error.
       //
    }

    // Store token and next
    //
    strcpy(tokens[totalTokens++], token);
}

return 0;
}
```

Hopefully ought to help.

Comment: I didn't DV, but your code doesn't appear to handle the case of empty strings, which OP wants to preserve (E.g. `a,b,,c` should produce a different result to `a,b,c`)

Comment: This does not work to your expectations before the question is changed.